# Overlapping controls in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have developed a Windows Desktop Application in VS 2010 in Windows 7; when I installed that application in Windows XP, some of the textboxes and labels overlap one another.

In short, after installing an application built on Windows 7 to Windows XP, the visual design process has failed me and my controls are now overlapped.

What can I look to resolve this?

Comment: Are any of the controls anchored to an outside window border? Are the app windows the same size on both O/S?

Comment: Are your controls themed?  Have you specified the correct comctl32 in your manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a mismatch in the DPI settings in the two operating systems.  From memory Windows 7 has a higher default setting to Windows XP.

How to check, change the value in both versions:

[Windows 7 - DPI Display Size Settings - Change](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html)

[To increase or decrease the size of objects and text on your screen](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/display_use_large_or_small_fonts.mspx?mfr=true)

If you wish to cater for both defaults you will need to design your application to cope with the differences.  Check out the the Control.Anchor and Control.Dock properties for details on how to ensure you controls size appropriately:

[Control.Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)

[Control.Dock Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Win7 and WinXP running at different DPI's? XP defaults to 96 dpi while Win7, I believe, defaults to 120. This can cause visual discrepancies like you are describing.

You can see the setting in Win7 at Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display. "Smaller" is 96 dpi and "Medium" is 120.