# UI Changes Size When Installed on Another Computer

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I've had a reoccurring issue with my programs' UI: they look fine in design mode and when run on my computer but look different/incorrect (e.g. squished, overlapped controls) when run on other computers.

Any idea what this could be? At first I thought it might be a 32/64-bit issue but it wasn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a minimal example reproducing the said problem?

Comment: I don't have an example ready but after some additional search-word combinations I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850431/overlapping-controls-in-windows-xp) which seems to be my issue (and matches @Kristopher suggestion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users can set their text size to be larger than normal, or choose a different font for controls.

Differing DPI settings can affect how things get laid out.

Answer (score 3):

This can potentially be down to several issues.

1. DPI. Affects the layout of form controls (Thanks to Kristopher Johnson for this one!)
2. Theme. (Classic, Aero, Luna)...generally speaking Microsoft themes will not have much affect from one to another and neither will well designed custom themes, but badly designed custom themes will suffer. Again as described by Kristopher Johnson, Font size settings in the theme will impact how the form renders. - Consideration: lets say you run your app on a Linux installation of Mono...will it still look the same?
3. Fonts. If your application uses a font that the other machine does not have, then that machine will substitute it for another "fallback" font. This can have an effect in some controls, for example a label, where the width of the label scales to the width of the text of the given font.

Answer (score -3):

There is a problem with Resolution.

Your machine has a different resolution than other machine, try to make design for resolution 1024X768

Comment: Controls will not overlap if the screen resolution decreases.  If anything, the window is drawn outside of the visible screen area.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case. Resolution does have an impact on how the form displays, and depends on the controls used. but generally speaking, the controls should be able to cope with changing resolutions. Take for example the ToolStrip. when too much content is to be displayed, it wraps the additional content into a menu, instead of squashing it!